# ckeditor5 mentions plugin change mention text

Tags: ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react, ckeditor5-plugin

i'm using ckeditor5 on react, and i want to achieve this:
i have list with keys and values - for example:

```
[{id: "@key1", value: "value1}, {id: "@key2", value: "value2"}]
```

and i want that when the editor is focused - the text shown will be `@keyX`, but when the editor is blurred - the text shown will be `valueX`.

i've tried multiple way with the helps of the docs [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html), but no good.

any idea?
any help (even saying - "it is not possible") will be mostly welcome!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try `{id: "@key1", text: "value1}`

As per: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_mention_mention-MentionFeedItem.html